# Airflow: Can a child task signal to Airflow that the immediate parent needs reran?

Tags: python, airflow

Our airflow retrieves reports from a website. We submit the parameters for the report and use a sensor to detect the status of it. Sometimes the system drops reports, and the sensor is setup to recognize when this happens. Instead of failing when this happens, is there a way to have the sensor task signal to the scheduler that itself and its parent task that submits the report need to be cleared so they can run again?

Answer (score 0):

With Airflow 2.0+ this is possible. You can use the airflow API to clear the task and its parent. The API call simply needs a list of tasks to clear so its super easy. Documentation can be found under Docs in the airflow interface.

Edit:
In the effort of being more clear, here is a more detailed explanation. I used a httpHook in my child task to make a call to my deployments ClearDagTask endpoint to clear the parent submit task. The child task was a sensor so i just had it reschedule itself while the parent task resubmitted the report request. The API swagger documentation can be found under Docs in your own deployment, at least with Astronomer, and explains everything you need to build the call.

Comment: How do you "use the airflow API"? Which specific API call are you referring to? What is the relevant part of the documentation? I don't think someone with a similar problem would find enough information in your answer to resolve it.

Comment: @polo-language hows that?